# How to copy all files by single extension

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

I have list of files a.xxx a.yyy. a.zzz

I need copy all files by select by extension
for example

```
ls *.xxx | xargs cp a.* dir
```

I write such code

`ls mysql/db/*.MYD | xargs -n1 basename | sed 's/\.MYD//g' | xargs -i cp mysql/db/{}.* new_folder`

but get error

```
cp: cannot stat 'mysql/db/ps_opc_social_customer.*'
```

Comment: if you're copying all the files of similar name, like of extension `*.xxx`, you can use `find` command, like : `find /path_name/ -type f -name "*.xxx" -exec cp {} /destination_path/ \;`

Comment: I need copy all files *.xxx *.yyy *.zzz by select by one extension *.xxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `*` in the last command gets expanded by the shell at the very instant when you press return, so the copy command does not get an expanded string, but the literal `<file>.*` string.
You need to get all the files you need in one go or to use a new shell to do the glob expansion for you:

```
ls mysql/db/*.MYD | xargs -n1 basename | sed 's/\.MYD//g' | xargs -i bash -c "cp mysql/db/{}.* new_folder"
```